# Corda for Digital Identites?

Tags: corda

Hi is Corda a recommended platform for Digital Identity? For a use-case of Account based-Certification.  (i.e. i as a user store my certificates/Identity on the ledger and access it via a password/key where i would go through a node, at the same time to allow a specified certificate only to be seen by a specified party. Where the control is on the user/account level and not a node level. Which means i could specify which certificate/identities i would want to allow another organisation to access)

for blockchain technologies I understand that the data is duplicated across all nodes as long as the user have the key the user can access his own data even if the node is a newly joined node to the network.

As i understand also Corda doesn't support multiple identities on a single node as it is node basis. What will be the approach for this case using Corda platform?

Answer (score 2):

first of all - Corda is not like Ethereum, Fabric and any other blockchain where all nodes store same common state. In Corda network nodes store only transactions and states they were participating in or observing. So its more peer-to-peer rather than broadcast.

Check here for more details:
https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-ledger.html

From this perspective Corda is probably not the best candidate for public Identity network.

For solution about self-sovereign identity management I would recommend to have a look at something like Sovrin(Indy). You can use it to build app on top of the platform. Or just learn their design ;)

Corda may have sense in Identity context if there are different organisations and they exchange its members identity info for some reason. Then node will be Identity Manager and store info about people who gave it its credentials of any kind. So Identity will be mere state here, I think. Corda itself will play transport and storage role. Not a blockchain-style decentralized way at all but may be useful in some cases.